# Why the given lexical specification will not process the following strings?

Tags: regular-expressions, compilers, lexical-analysis

I'm taking a Compiler MOOC on my own time. The class is self paced. An answer was given to a question but I can't understand the answer. In fact I'm not even sure how to interpret the question.

Here is the question:

> Given the following lexical specification:
>
> $(00)^*$
> $01^+$
> $10^+$
>
> Which strings are NOT successfully processed by this
> specification?
>
> 1. $0111110$
> 2. $01100110$
> 3. $0001101$
> 4. $01100100$

The correct answers are 1 and 2. But I can't figure out why. How do I interpret this lexical specification? Can someone help me out with this.

Comment: Hint: the "specification" is probably intended to mean $(00)^* + 01^+ + 10^+$ (plus priorities, which you don't need to care about for this exercise). So the question reduces to "which strings match this regular expression?" (which I'd expect you to be able to do yourself if you want to take this course).

Comment: I do not see why the question is downvoted. It is interesting and well stated. It could contain some more details on why the poster could not figure out why the correct answers are 1 and 2. But then, no one said anything about that in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The strings not processed successfully are 1, 2, and 3.** Only string 4 is processed successfully.

I think your problem is not with interpreting the meaning of regular
expressions, but in understanding the process of [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), at
least as intended in your course.

Normally, a regular expression is supposed to match a string from
beginning to end. But when doing lexical analysis of a program, you
are supposed to cut the program text in small chunks coresponding to
the lexical elements of the language, which in turn can be taken (up
to some details not relevant here) as the terminal alphabet of the
(usually Context-Free) grammar used to define the language you are parsing.

So, during lexical analysis, you have nothing to indicate the end of a
lexical element, as the program text goes on to give the next lexical
element. For example, if you are scanning the string $foobar$, is it
the identifier $f$ followed by $oobar$, or $foo$ followed by $bar$, or
$fo$ followed by $oba$ and $r$. For a strict lexical point of view,
all these possibilities would be correct ... though the grammatical
parser that will use the lexical element can be unhappy with some
choices.

To simplify matters, a simple rule is often followed by [scanners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Scanner) performing lexical analysis, called [maximal munch rule, or longest match rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch). It works as follows:

While recognizing a lexical element, the lexical analyzer
will keep reading the input string as long as it is reading a prefix
of a lexical element, according to the lexical specification, and will
halt when the next symbol to be read would no longer constitute such a
prefix if added to the part of the input already scanned. At that
point, if the scanned string corresponds to a complete lexical element
(i.e. the scanning automaton is in an accepting state), this lexical
element has been recognized. If it is only a prefix of a lexical
element that cannot be completed with what follows into a proper
lexical element, you have a lexical analysis error.

Thus with your example 1, $0111110$, the lexical analyser will start
recognizing the second regular expression $01^+$, and will scan
$011111$ as one lexical element. Then it is left with only $0$ which
is the prefix of a word in the first two regular expression $(00)^*$
and $01^+$. But then the string stops, so that it cannot be part of a
complete lexical element. hence the lexical analysis fails with an
error at that point.

You could say that if you had stopped the first lexical element one
symbol earlier, thus recognizing $01111$. Then you would be left with
$10$ which is recognizable by the third regular expression $10^+$. But
that is not how things work. There is no [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) (actually, some [scanners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Scanner) have more complex rules allowing for some backtrack, for example for the programming language C). Allowing this
would also make thigs a lot more ambiguous as I explained in the
$foobar$ example.

In the second example $01100110$, you get $011$, then $00$, and you
are left with $110$. The first $1$ is a prefix for the regex $10^+$,
but it should then be followed by at least one $0$, which is not
there. Hence lexical analysis fails.

However, the third example $0001101$ should fail too. The reason is
that symbols are read one by one. The first $0$ is a prefix for both
regex $(00)^*$ and $01^+$. But, on scanning the second $0$, we know we
are looking for a lexical element defined by the forst regex
$(00)^*$. Then the third $0$ is ok too, since $000$ is a prefix of
$0000$ which is recognized by the first regex. So it is scanned. But
now we need a $0$, and we find a $1$. So the lexical analysis fails.

My guess is that the designer of the exercise recognize too quickly
that it could work, by stopping one $0$ early (and I did too the first
time I read this). But the computer does not have this global
perception, and proceeds one symbol at a time.

The fourth example $01100100$ works fine, yielding $011$, $00$, and $100$.

**If backtracking were allowed**, all four strings could be scanned into
lexical elements.

But the fourth string could then be scanned as:

- $011$, $00$, $100$, or
- $01$, $10$, $01$, $00$

Though you can use a rule that you backtrack only in case of failure,
to avoid such an ambiguous situation.

*Of course, there is the possibility that your instructor defined things differently, but this is the best I can do with the information I have.*

Comment: You nailed it. I did have a problem understanding lexical analysis process. This is a great explanation. My understanding is that there is also a priority involved. The expressions above have a higher priority than the expressions below. But even using these rules I still can't come up with the answer the professor gave.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how priority can work well, with an efficient and intuitive algorithm (intuitive is needed for people to be able to read programs). Can you ask what the precise rules are, as this can vary somewhat, as I explain in the answer? There is also the possibility that he goofed on one example (third?), we all do on occasion.

Comment: I posted a question asking for a proper explanation on the MOOC website but as this is a self-paced course, I doubt I'll get an answer to it any time soon.

Comment: Here is another question that I was not able to answer. It is similar to the one I asked
Given the following lexical specification:

$a(ba)^*$<br />
$b*(ab)^*$<br />
$abd$<br />
$d^+$<br />
Which of the following statements is true?

1. $babad$ will be tokenized as: $bab/a/d$ 
2. $ababdddd$ will be tokenized as: $abab/dddd$
3. $dddabbabab$ will be tokenized as: $ddd/a/bbabab$
4. $ababddababa$ will be tokenized as: $ab/abd/d/ababa$. 

Correct answers are 1 and 2. Maybe collectively we will be able to derive a correct set of rules.

Comment: @flashburn This seems in agreement with my answer, using longest match rule. Did you see a discrepancy?

Comment: I can't understand why $ababdddd$ was tokenized as $abab / dddd$. Why wasn't it tokenized as $aba / b / dddd$?

Comment: Same as before. Each regular expression stands for one type of token,
and you choose the one that makes the longest token. The string $aba$
can be a token of first type, but extended to $abab$ it makes a longer
token of the second kind. So the second solution will be preferred
irrespective of what may come later (unless it can make an even longer
token). The is the intuitive explanation. Actually, all the regular
expression are compiled into a unique automaton that does just that.

Comment: No problem ... it happens more often then one would think, and I can be slow myself. But, I think it is good to preserve the habit. Also, I have the feeling that the system tends to bring questions ask periodically as long as there is no accepted answer. This is a bit disruptive. Glad I could help. If you get an answer from your MOOC, remember me. P.S. I do not know why you were downvoted: I think the question was well asked, and new afaik, and interesting fo some users. Maybe you could have explained more why you could not figure out why the correct answer was 1 and 2.